# Communicating Message Broker and Websphere Application Server

Tags: websphere-portal, websphere-8, messagebroker

I have a portal application deployed on WebSphere Portal server and message flows deployed in message broker execution group. The portal application does some kind of database CRUD operation. Based on the changes made through portal, I want to update my cache data of Message Broker. Since there could be several broker execution group, so I thought of creating a pub-sub model. Every time the portal changes some values in the database, it publishes that message to the topic which broker application will listen to and take appropriate action.

My problem is how to make both these servers communicate to each other. Any pointer would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMS would probably be my choice here as it already supports the pub/sub semantics and is supported by both products.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use DatabaseInput Node in You Message Flows, this Node can listens on Database,Table,or Column if you want for more information go to this link and read about the Node:
[DatabaseInput Node Documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bc34041_.htm)

[image: DatabaseInput Node Snapshot]